# RV's with same mean/variance satisying Ohlin's lemma

Tags: distributions, random-variable, cumulative-distribution-function

I am trying to find two random variables X,Y with same mean and variance such that Ohlin's Lemma holds. That is, there exists some $x_0$ such that $F_X(x) \leq F_Y(x)$ for $x < x_0$ and $F_X(x) \geq F_Y(x)$ for $x \geq x_0$. I have found about 20+ distributions with same mean and variance now (which isn't that difficult), but absolutely none of them satisfies these conditions.

Anyone with an idea to what random variables might work here?

Comment: This may be impossible. For instance, I verified with Mathematica that if $X$ is an ordinary fair die, and $Y$ is an unfair die with the same faces, it is impossible for $X$ and $Y$ to have this property.